# Text wrapping expands the column to fit the text

Tags: wpf, word-wrap

I've got a grid defined simply:

```
<Grid Margin="0,5,0,0">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="48"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Then I'm trying to bind some content like this:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Text}">
```

Set up like this, the text won't wrap. It simply expands the column to fit the text. If I set the Width to a fixed amount on the last column, wrapping works as expected. The problem there is that if the user widens the window, the column stays at a fixed size. How can I get the column to size dynamically with the width of the grid, but still wrap the text within it?

Answer (score 5):

A width of `"*"` will split any remaining space evenly between the columns using `"*"`. If you have a single column with `Width="*"`, that column will get all remaining space. If you have 2 columns with `Width="*"`, each will get 1/2 of the remaining space.

Here's a [good article on grid sizing](http://www.wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html) that includes star sizing.

Answer (score 5):

There's one frustrating case I discovered that can break even with `Width="*"` and thats when you have [`IsSharedSizeScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)`= true`.

```
<Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
    <StackPanel Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">

        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="G1"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="G2" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  SharedSizeGroup="G3" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="Col0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Col1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>

            <TextBlock Text="A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="2"/> 
        </Grid>

    </StackPanel>                   

</Border>
```

This won't wrap, but if you change `Grid.IsSharedScopeSize` to `false` then it does.

Haven't found a solution yet, but this can be another reason it won't work.

Comment: Note: A deleted answer in reference to my answer said "This won't work, because shared size columns ignore Width property and consider it set to Auto. So you end up with the same setup as Ben in the original question."

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<Grid Margin="0,5,0,0">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="48"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Name="ParentColumn" Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Text}"
      MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ParentColumn}">
```

Answer (score -1):

Set its width to "*"

Answer (score -1):

You should use Auto only when you want to column/row to size depending on content in said column/row. If you want to "asign rest of space" use "*".
In your case, TextBlock needs to know how much space it has before acutal measure, so it can tell where to wrap the text.